# How can I create composite entities which include other entities without a space between them?

Tags: dialogflow-es

For example i want to create an entity to match voltage values like:

`5 V, 5 volt, 5 v, etc...`

I give composite entity values like:

`@sys.number V, @sys.number volt, @sys.number v, etc...`

However user often write like:

`"I am looking for a 5v lamp"`

In order to create examples without space i try,

`{@sys.number}V, {@sys.number}volt, {@sys.number}v, etc...`

But it doesn't work. What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Entities,

Create a new entity and give the name as 5v,

`Enter reference value` as `5v` and `enter synonyms` as `5 V, 5 volts, 5 v, 5v,5V` or every possibility that you can think.

Save the entity and go back to your intent now when you add the question in
`user expression` it will automatically detect the entity as `@5v` because we gave a name to an entity as `5v`

Comment: yes but i just need all numbers to be matched like for example it can be length. in this case it can be `5m` or `32423m` i just need it working with a number entity like `@sys.number`.

Comment: I am not sure but try `@sys.unit-length-name` or whatever you prefer

Comment: Yep that is another option but i have a huge database which system entities don't include all of them. I need to create my own measurement entities.